# Trying to use a VGA monitor with my Raspberry PI

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, android-things

I have Android things 0.5.1 Dev Preview installed in my Raspberry Pi 3. In my office with an HDMI monitor, it works just fine. But when I use an HDMI to VGA converter I do see the Rainbow screen. But the Android Things logo won't show up.

Could someone tell me where the issue is exactly? I see the Rainbow screen does that mean that HDMI to VGA is working? Is there an issue in the OS?

Comment: It's rather an unsupported feature then an issue.